# show active and inactive categories magento for parent level

Tags: magento, categories

I have a website in magento. i want show all categories whether it is active or not.

I have tried but it doesnt show inactive categories.

Can any give a suggestion to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
    <?php 

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addLevelFilter(2);

$b_path = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
?> 
<div class="nav-container">
<ul id="nav">
<?php
foreach($categories as $cat)
{
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getentity_id()); 
if($category ->getname() == 'Root Catalog' || $category ->getname() == 'Default Category' )
{}else{
?>



<li><a href="<?php echo $b_path.$category ->geturl_path() ?>"><?php echo $category ->getname(); ?></a></li>
<?php }} ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try this one... this will surely help you...

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')//or you can just add some attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level;
```

add this filter option if you want all active categories.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')//or you can just add some attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level
  ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);//if you want only active categories
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this link, may be help you,

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/*
 * http://fishpig.co.uk - Magento Tutorials
 *
 * Display top level categories and subcategories
 *
**/
?>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```